# Characterization of Complex Group Algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Is there a way to characterize which complex algebras arise as the group algebra of some locally compact group? To make this more concrete, say $A$ is a sub-algebra of $\text{Mat}(n,\mathbb{C})$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Are there any conditions under which there exist criterion to determine whether $A$ is the group algebra of some subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$? I am also interested in similar results for finite groups.

Comment: When you say group algebra, are you completing this in some norm? (Otherwise your mention of "locally compact groups" sounds strange.) If so, do you mean $L^1(G)$, or $C_r^*(G)$, or $C^*(G)$, or something else?

Comment: I mean $C_c(G)$ - continuous compactly supported functions. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The paper

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1102994980

of Rieffel characterizes group algebras of groups over the reals as ordered algebras (ordering functions on the group pointwise).

Comment: That is finite groups.

Comment: If the group is locally compact but not finite, isn't it impossible for $C_c(G)$ to be finite-dimensional?